# Call canadapost autocomplete api to fill in the text box in angular

Tags: angular, api

How can I proceed with calling the canadapost service API to autofill address information using angular.

I dont need code related to the http call.Am looking more towards how to make this call on change of the textbox.

I have got addressline1, addressline2, city, province, postal code, country text box fields on the UI. When I type on any of the boxes it should autofill in all the fields.

Below is the API am trying to use

https://ws1.postescanada-canadapost.ca/AddressComplete/Interactive/AutoComplete/v1.00/json3.ws?Key=APIKEY&SearchTerm=6366

Sample JSON:

```
{
  "Items": [
    {
      "Id": "CA|CP|A|9844581",
      "Text": "6366-1150 Rue Des Quatre-Saisons",
      "Highlight": "0-4",
      "Description": "Sherbrooke, QC, J1E 3X3",
      "IsRetrievable": true
    },
    {
      "Id": "CA|CP|A|281990",
      "Text": "6366 Ashworth Pl",
      "Highlight": "0-4",
      "Description": "Burnaby, BC, V5E 3V3",
      "IsRetrievable": true
    },
    {
      "Id": "CA|CP|ENG|QC-MONTR\u00C9AL+NORD-RUE_PIERRE-6366|NjM2NiBSdWUgUGllcnJl",
      "Text": "6366 Rue Pierre",
      "Highlight": "0-4",
      "Description": "Montr\u00E9al-Nord, QC, H1G 1P2",
      "IsRetrievable": false
    }
}
```

How to implement this with angular 7?

Comment: please post JSON result to your question too

Comment: Use the [edit] link, don't add things to the comments